# Why do I get wrong location coordinates when using hit test in ARKit through RoboVM?

Tags: java, arkit, hittest, robovm

I am trying to develop a test AR app with ARKit using RoboVM. After setting up the session with a ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and running it, I would like to determine a position on a detected horizontal plane (floor) by running a hit test like so:

```
public void addTapGestureToSceneView(){
    UITapGestureRecognizer uiTapGestureRec = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
    uiTapGestureRec.addListener(new UIGestureRecognizer.OnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGesture(UIGestureRecognizer uiGestureRecognizer) {
            CGPoint tapLocation = uiGestureRecognizer.getLocationInView(arView);
            NSArray<ARHitTestResult> hitTestResults = arView.hitTest(tapLocation, ARHitTestResultType.FeaturePoint);

            if(!hitTestResults.isEmpty()) {
                VectorFloat3 vec3 = getTranslation(hitTestResults.last().getWorldTransform());
                addBox(vec3);
            }
        }
    });
    arView.addGestureRecognizer(uiTapGestureRec);
}
```

(`getTranslation(...)` is a helper method extracting the third column of a transformation matrix)
In `addBox(VectorFloat3 position)` a node with a box geometry is added.

The problem is, that this always returns hit test coordinates with all three components close to zero (e.g. x*10^-35), so the box is added almost at the center of the phone I am testing this app with.

Is there something wrong with my implementation or could that be a bug in RoboVM?

---

**Update:**
Problem solved in newer version of RoboVM.
See pull request: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/pull/339
and: https://dkimitsa.github.io/2018/12/11/vector-data-types/

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in robovm obj compiler code that caused vector data types (SIMD ones) wrongly marshaled (as generic structs) that is against ABI. It cause garbage when targeting ARM64 and GPF when running simulator. It is already fixed and merged to master. Also available in 2.3.6-SNAPSHOT build.
Check this pr for details https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/pull/339

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the link here, and provide the link for reference.